# WPF ItemsControl style with connecting lines like a timeline

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I'm trying to design an ItemsControl with a timeline that shows the sub items connected with arrows/lines.
The items are custom controls, and i'd like to connect the lines to the control's borders.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Usually I'd ask what you tried, but this isn't too hard, share your itemscontrol xaml and an example of what you want it to look like and when time permits can show you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is the code for the Itemscontrol:

```
 <ItemsControl DataContext="{StaticResource StratCol1}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        </ItemsControl>
```

This is the items collection:

```
<ctrl:StrategyCollection x:Key="StratCol1" >
        <ctrl:StrategyNode Height="150" Width="Auto" Title="Title A" StrategyParameter="{StaticResource dpara}" Period="All year" IsChecked="False"/>
        <ctrl:StrategyNode Height="150" Width="Auto" Title="Title B" StrategyParameter="{StaticResource dpara}" Period="3 Months" IsChecked="False" />
    </ctrl:StrategyCollection>
```

And this is the style of the items:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:StrategyNode}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />


        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:StrategyNode}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="xBorderBrush"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="xBorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource ControlCheckedBackColor}" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="xBorderBrush"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource ControlCheckedColor}" />

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="xBorderBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Transparent" />


                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


                         <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="1" >
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush  x:Name="xBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource ControlBorderColor}"/>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>

                                <Border.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush  x:Name="xBorderBackground" Color="{StaticResource ControlBackColor}"/>
                                </Border.Background>

                                <Grid >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="8,8,0,0" Height="18.4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlTitleBackColor}" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Foreground="AliceBlue" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"  />
                                    </Border>


                                    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Content="Period"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Period, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                                        <Grid x:Name="ParametersGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                            <Label Content="Qos" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Avg_Qos, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                            <Label Content="Safty Range" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Avg_SaftyRange, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                            <Label Content="TT in days" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Avg_TimeToDeliverInDays, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>



                                        </Grid>

                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>

                            </Border>




                    </Grid>


                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thank you for your help.